# How to search for duplicates with cutting of a specified value

Tags: mysql

I need a query to find duplicates, but one of the values will always have an extension (always the same one).

Example:
two column values:
`name`: ABC
`name`: ABC_xxx

Now I need a SELECT query, that can cut of the extension "_xxx" to find the duplicate name "ABC".

I tried solving this with some concat queries, but with no success.
Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks!
Jo

Comment: have you tried ```like "%ABC"```

Comment: yeah, of course this would work, but "ABC" is just the example.
it can as well be something else - only the extension will always be the same

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: select count(*) from table where name like 'passedvalue%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will handle multiple instances of _ before the extension and will give you the duplicates with their counts

```
select name, count(*)
from 
(select left(name,length(name)-length(substring_index(name,'_',-1))-1) as name from test) t
group by name 
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: what if I need to replace another extension, let's say 'yyy' - how does this work? Replaceing two extensions and then show me the duplicates

Comment: @user11907359 I modified my answer so it can take care of any extension as long as it starts with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
select * 
from table without_extension
join table with_extension
where without_extension.name = 
    left(with_extension.name, length(with_extension.name) - 4)
```

This should strip the name by removing the last 4 characters `(length(with_extension.name) - 4`), and comparing it to the name without extension.

Answer (score 0):

If the extension always starts _ then substring_index may do

```
set @a = 'name:abc';
set @b = 'name:abc_xxx';

select  substring_index(substring_index(@a,':',-1),'_',1) as a,
        substring_index(substring_index(@b,':',-1),'_',1) as b;

+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| abc  | abc  |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```